# How to remove circles from new polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, circle

I've just started using QGIS (2.6.0-Brighton).  Every time I create a new polygon, a circle appears in the center (see below).  I thought this might just be a feature of QGIS editing that helps you to distinguish between new polygons, but the circles stay there even in the print composer and exported maps.  Any ideas on how to remove them?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Layer-Properties-Style. I guess that your layer has something like "Centroid fill" in the renderings styles. Remove it. If you are just beginning to use QGIS you should have no reason to start with 2.6 because the current version is 2.14.

Comment: Neither of the polygons use 'centroid fill'.  But I've just realised that for some reason 'display diagrams' was switched on in the 'Diagrams' tab (in Layer Properties).  This seems to have resolved it.  Thanks for your suggestions - I'm in the process of downloading the latest QGIS now!